# How to get back the button state from detailview to tableview with NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, delegates

I made this to change the states off a button. It's a bookmark style button. If the user want to bookmark a detail view, he click on a star. And i want to get back the information in the root view.

Here is my code for the detailview.m

```
- (IBAction)saveRow
{
 NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *save = cellNumber;

if ([buttonSave.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Sync off"]) {
    [prefs setValue:@"YES" forKey:save];
    [buttonSave setTitle:@"Sync on" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonSave setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clicked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else {
    [prefs setValue:@"NO" forKey:save];
    [buttonSave setTitle:@"Sync off" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonSave setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notclicked.gif"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

// save
[prefs synchronize];
}



#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:cellNumber])
{
    [buttonSave setTitle:@"Sync on" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonSave setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clicked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else {
    [buttonSave setTitle:@"Sync off" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonSave setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notclicked.gif"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

But in the rootview, i don't know what to do to do the same thing. The rootview is a tableview.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

U can define a delegate in the `DetailViewController` that the `RootViewController` will implement.

```
@protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)detailViewController:(DetailViewController *)controller didBookmarkSomthing:(Something *)something

@end
```

Then the `RootViewController` will implement this method and from `something` he will know to update the UI.

Having said that I usually do this kind of things in the model layer - u change the state of the model, then tell who ever is interested about this change.
For example suppose u have a table view of books - so my model here is a list of `Book` objects.
Now when user tap on one of the books I push a detail view controller, lets call it `BookDetailViewController` that shows the book's info.
When I push this controller I pass the `Book` object to it, usually I create a special init method that also gets the `Book`, like this:

```
- (id)initWithBook:(Book *)aBook
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.book = aBook;
    }  
    return self;  
}
```

Now whatever u do in this view controller should infect the `Book` object, for example if u want to enable user bookmark a book action (just an example..) then u need to add a `isBookmarked` property to the `Book` object to tell u if a book is bookmark or not.
 Then when user press the bookmark button in the `BookDetailViewController` change the model as well - `self.book.isBookmarked = YES;`

Now your model is changed and u need to update who ever wants to know about this changes, I like to do this with a notification.
For example Book object will define `BookDidChangedBookmarkStateNotification`, and post this notification when the bookmark state changed.
Your `RootViewController` will listen to this notification and handle the uI changes.

Comment: wow, ok.. Thank you very much for your answer and great explanation. I think i will need 1 week to learn all those new expression. So i have to put a protocol on my detailView, and an init method in my root view? So the delegates are the key..

Comment: The key is to manage this kind of states in your model, usually it's not enough to tell your RootViewController about the change("something is now bookmark" in your case) so it can just update the UI. U need to update your model and then your model should update the RootViewController with delegates or notifications. If u want my advise, take your time learning those important patterns and come back to write your code, it will be much simpler then...

Comment: I will follow your advise, it seems too important to not understanding it! thanks!